# I keep getting logged out

Tags: bug, logout

I keep getting logged out of [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7573/599). I don't seem to be affected on other sites.

This just started happening today, but It's happened maybe 4-5 times so far.
Is this a bug?

Comment: I've had the same today although in my case it only seems to be Cooking.SE affected, but otherwise similar and all the regular sites I visit except that one seem OK.

Comment: I've had the same on Stack Overflow, and RPG.SE, and other sites. Seems to only happen on sites where I've had the StackEgg open.

Comment: Yeah, that happens if you didn't participate positively in the StackEgg challenge.

Comment: Please check your browser cache this also happens if you have not enable and store cache.

Comment: It does seem like it's related to stackegg.. But I didn't do anything I would call "negative participation" with stackegg on B.SE..

Comment: @rene, what did you mean by "didn't participate positively"? In one way it might match up with my experience on Cooking.SE because unlike other sites where I visited StackEgg I only did a couple of votes, although none were restarts and I voted in the direction to improve things.

Comment: We're looking into this now, unsure of the cause but a few of us are able to reproduce - stand by working it ASAP.

Comment: @Nick is [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284475/i-keep-getting-logged-out-off-stack-overflow-on-chrome) related?