# I keep getting logged out off Stack Overflow on Chrome

Tags: support, stack-overflow, login

For the last month or so - I keep getting logged out of Stack Overflow. It happens whenever I go to another page - about every minute or so. Sometimes I get logged out - and sometimes it works fine. But it's incredibly annoying and makes the website impossible to use.

I have cleared all my Stack Overflow cookies - yet this seems to NOT help at all. Any one else having this issue? I've been reading other posts on here from past years - no good advice anywhere.

Comment: What is your Chrome version? Have you tried disabling all extensions? Do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: I am using Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit). I have NOT tried disabling extensions but i will. I will look out for errors. thanks!

Comment: New ISP? Or existing one that is now doing something strange with IP addresses? Did you try another browser?

Comment: I did move to a new place so I have a new ISP - I have NOT tried another browser.

Comment: Try a different browser, just to rule things out. Also - you can check if your public IP address is changing by going to https://www.whatismyip.com and refreshing the page a few times to see if it changes.

Comment: @Gothdo, I deleted every extension I had. That seemed to resolve the issue. thank you

Answer (score 2):

As question author [said in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284475/i-keep-getting-logged-out-off-stack-overflow-on-chrome#comment922837_284475), deleting all the browser extensions resolved the issue.